# Styling contact form results in an email

Tags: php, css, forms, email, styles

I am wondering how can i style an emailed contact form results.  Meaning, when a person fills out my contact form, when the results come to me in an email, I wanted that results to come in a stylistic way.

Here is my contact form, Just a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="PHP_Email_Form.php">

   <label>First Name:  <input type="text" name="First Name" size="30" maxlength="30" />   
   </label>

   <label>Last Name:  <input type="text" name="First Name" size="30" maxlength="30" />   
   </label>

   <textarea name="Comments" rows="8" cols="50"  style="margin-left:37px" />
   </textarea>

   <input type="submit" value="submit"  />

</form>
```

My PHP Script:

```
<?php
  $to = 'dew02d@yahoo.com';
  $subject = 'Client feed back';
  $message= '';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$message .= $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}

mail($to, $subject, $message);

header('Location:/contactThx.htm');
?>
```

Comment: `style an emailed contact form results` you can use html in images in emails you know

Comment: just include inline HTML in the `$message` variable and if HTML is enabled by your email provider then it should display.

Comment: could u send me an example or write an example urself?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should shift your self to PHPMailer Library. this library will allow you to send stylistic and HTML emails.

Kindly follow the follwing URL that will let you know the way to send a stylistic email into mailbox.

http://www.computersneaker.com/send-email-using-phpmailer/

You can attach images into your email with this tutorial.

Comment: This is a good one however, it doesn't do exactly what I wanted it to do, I need to stylize the actual input of what users fill out in the contact form.  Meaning "First Name" "Last Name" "Phone Number" etc. How do u style or inline style PHP code? Do u do it the same way as HTML?

Comment: simply made that an HTML format and then inline style that HTML file and send that into your email box. this is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML tags in your message body, and add a content-type header in your email:

```php
$to = 'dew02d@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Client feed back';
$message= '';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$message .= '<strong>' . $key . '</strong>' . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location:/contactThx.htm');
```

Comment: Hey Guys, I am still confused. I need some one to actually style my php code so I can exactly see how you did it. I am looking at all these examples and examples on google and its still not registering.  Here is the link:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMyuJ/7/

Comment: Meaning I copy that exact code u put in the example (<strong> </strong>) and this was the results:              <strong>First_Name</strong>: Derek
<strong>Last_ _Name</strong>: Walk
<strong>Phone_Number</strong>: 
<strong>Email</strong>: dew@yahoo.com
<strong>Comments</strong>: test   I'm trying to stylize the results on the form post that was sent to my email.  This is the link:  http://darrylsportfolio.netai.net/contact.html